# $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-f(-x))=0$ show that $f'(x_0)=0$

Tags: calculus

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ $f$ is derivable in all of $\mathbb R$.
>
> Let $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-f(-x))=0$
>
> Show that there exists $x_0\in\mathbb R$ such that $f'(x_0)=0$.

From intuiton I see that $f$ is an even function because $f(x)=f(-x)$ so it can either be like for example $f(x)=x^2$ which has an extramum point where $f'(x_0)=0$ or $f(x)=c, \ c\in\mathbb R$ which is also an even function and the derivative is always 0.

I'm not really sure how to formally prove it.

Note: we can't use integrals.

Comment: $f$ is not neccesarily even, it can behave however it like around the origin, we only know that $f(x) = f(-x)$ as $x$ tends to infinity.

Comment: $f$ need not be an even function, since all you have is the limit. On any bounded interval $[-K,K]$, it can be arbitrarily far from even. The key is that a derivative has the intermediate value property, even if it is not continuous.

Comment: @naslundx can I claim that $f$ is even for $\forall x : \exists M\in \mathbb R : x>M$ ?

Comment: @GinKin No, not even that.

Comment: $f$ even means $f(x)-f(-x)=0$ identically, whereas here we have $f(x)-f(-x)=\epsilon(x)$ for some function $\epsilon$ that vanishes as $x\to\pm\infty$ but which could actually be never $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Claim:** Let $f\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ continuous with $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-f(-x))=0$. Then there exists $x_0\in\mathbb R$ where $f$ has a local extremum.
Especially, if $f$ is differentiable, there exists $x_0\in\mathbb R$ with $f'(x_0)=0$

*Proof:* 
Note that continuous functions assume their maximum/minimum on every compact interval. Unless the extremum is at an endpoint of the interval, it is a local extremum of $f$.
If $f(-1)=f(1)$, we are done (if $f(-1)=f(1)$ is both max and min of $f|_{[-1,1]}$ then $f$ is constant on that interval and all interioir points are local extrema). So wlog. $f(-1)<f(1)$ (or else replace $f$ with $-f$). Then  $d:=f(1)-f(-1)>0$. By assumption, there exists $L$ such that $x>L$ implies $|f(x)-f(-x)|<d$. Especially, for $c=\max\{L,1\}+1$ we have $f(c)<f(1)$ or $f(-c)>f(-1)$. In the first case $f(-1)<f(1)>f(c)$ shows that the maximum of $f|_{[-1,c]}$ is at an interior point $x_0\in(-1,c)$. In the second case, $f(-c)>f(-1)<f(1)$ shows that the minimum of $f|_{[-c,1]}$ is at an interior point $x_0\in(-c,1)$. $_\square$

Answer (score 0):

Sketch/Hint of proof:

If $f$ is the constant function, $f^\prime=0$ identically, so we may assume that $f$ is not constant.

Let $x_1<x_2$ such that $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$. Without loss of generality, we may assume $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$, so that $f^\prime(y)>0$ for some $x_1<y<x_2$.

Now, if the limits of $f(x)$ as $x\to\pm\infty$ coincide there can be two possibilities: either this limit is $\pm\infty$ or is finite, say $=L$.

If the limits are not finite, it should be clear that the function is decreasing somewhere and increasing somewhere else, so that $f^\prime=0$ at some point in between.

If the limits are finite, you get to the same conclusion comparing $L$ with $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ (may need to subdivide this into cases)

---

So we are reduced to prove that if $f$ is a function with no limit as $x\to\infty$ then the function cannot be monotone.

By contradiction let $f$ be monotone (increasing, since our assumption on $x_1<x_2$) and let $S=\sup f$.

If $S=\infty$, for all $N>0$ there exists $\bar x$ such that $f(\bar x)>N$. By monotonicity $f(x)>N$ for all $x\geq\bar x$, which means that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$.

If $S$ is finite, for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\bar x$ such that $S-\epsilon<f(\bar x)<S$. By monotonicity $f(x)\in(S-\epsilon,S+\epsilon)$ for all $x\geq\bar x$, which means that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=S$.

In both cases we reach a contradiction.

Comment: The limits of $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$ don't have to exist separately. (For example, if $f(x)=\cos x$.)

Comment: @HansLundmark : good point! I think I fixed it (see edit)